# Creating a floating document property control that is available in all tabs of Spotfire dashboard

Tags: jquery, ironpython, spotfire, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

[Spotfire]How to use the *same* spotfire Document property control element across different tabs of Spotfire dashboard to trigger Ironpython script ?  Currently I have a javascript that sets the documentproperty via a Documentproperty control which activates the Ironpython script. We use JQuery UI dialog for the javascript. I want to have this property available to all tabs within the Dashboard. How should I define the Documentproperty control so it can be used to activate the Ironpython script from any tab ?

I created a floating JS control, but this does not update the documentproperty if I switch tabs.  The only solution that works currently is if I create a documentProperty control in a Text area for each tab.

```
    $("#testInput").dialog({

    autoOpen: false,

   }); 

$("#myAlertButton").click(openDialog);

function openDialog(){

      $("#testInput").dialog( "open" );

}

function refresh(){
    document.location.reload();
    }
```

​

I expect the floating control value to be reflected in the documentProperty, but it does not change.

Answer (score 2):

Is it necessary that it float?  If it doesn't need to float, just reuse the property in a text area and then you don't need JavaScript for this.

Comment: this is the Y to the X, I think ;) hard to say what OP is truly trying to achieve, but this is the easiest solution based on my interpretation, too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible.

turn on Developer Tools under Tools>>Options>>Application: Show developer tools, then open it under Tools>>Development>>Developer tools.

now expand the DOM a bit and find some element in the current page of your analysis. change the page. you'll see that the previous page isn't hidden; it's completely removed from the DOM.

now, you *may* be able to hack around this by injecting your `#testInput` *above* the page with something like `$("body").append("#testInput");`. this would probably keep it in the DOM through page changes, but I haven't tested this and it certainly isn't supported behavior.

keep in mind that, especially in version 10 and above, *the entire interface* is the DOM, even in the Analyst client. messing with the outer DOM structure can break the whole interface if you're not careful. do **a lot** of testing :)

Comment: Thanks Niko. Let me try this and get back. This solution might not scale especially when we deploy as a general library. But thank you for your input.

Comment: would love to know how you wind up solving this. it seems like an interesting use case :)